# Not being able to inference TensorFlow model hosted by kfserving component in Kubeflow

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, knative-serving

Hi so I am using kfserving v.0.5.1 component for hosting the model. I am able to download and deploy model from s3 but facing issue when try to access it.

After deployment kfserving outputted the following endpoint

```
http://recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.example.com
```

which I was not able to access it from outside and inside the node. After looking around I set my ingress-gateway to `LoadBalancer` from `NodePort` and added sslip.io to config-map config-domain of knative-serving

I followed [knative-dn-config](https://knative.dev/docs/install/installing-istio/#configuring-dns)

```
<IPofMyLB>.sslip.io: ""
```

after that I try to inference model but getting no error or response from server

```
curl -d '{"instances": ["abc"]}'   -X POST http://recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.<IPofMyLB>.sslip.io/v1/models/recommendation-model:predict
```

I try to simply get the inference endpoint and output is this:

```
curl -v -X GET http://recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ELBIP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io (ELBIP) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< location: /dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&state=MTYyMjY0MjU5M3xFd3dBRUV4MVVERkljREpRVUc1SVdXeDFaVkk9fOEnkjCWGNj6WPOgFhv2BUwNSKHsYyBR2kyj9_0geX2f
< date: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 14:03:13 GMT
< content-length: 269
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
< server: istio-envoy
<
<a href="/dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&amp;redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=profile+email+groups+openid&amp;state=MTYyMjY0MjU5M3xFd3dBRUV4MVVERkljREpRVUc1SVdXeDFaVkk9fOEnkjCWGNj6WPOgFhv2BUwNSKHsYyBR2kyj9_0geX2f">Found</a>.

* Connection #0 to host recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io left intact
* Closing connection 0
(base) ahsan@Ahsans-MacBook-Pro kfserving % curl -v -X GET http://recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ELBIP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io (ELBIP) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< location: /dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&response_type=code&scope=profile+email+groups+openid&state=MTYyMjY0MzE3OXxFd3dBRUhOdmFrSk9iVkU0Wms1VmMzVnhXbkU9fECJ3_U0SaWkR441eIWq-AJbFAV29-2Bk8uxPAOxPJD0
< date: Wed, 02 Jun 2021 14:12:59 GMT
< content-length: 269
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 1
< server: istio-envoy
<
<a href="/dex/auth?client_id=kubeflow-oidc-authservice&amp;redirect_uri=%2Flogin%2Foidc&amp;response_type=code&amp;scope=profile+email+groups+openid&amp;state=MTYyMjY0MzE3OXxFd3dBRUhOdmFrSk9iVkU0Wms1VmMzVnhXbkU9fECJ3_U0SaWkR441eIWq-AJbFAV29-2Bk8uxPAOxPJD0">Found</a>.

* Connection #0 to host recommendation-model.kubeflow-user-example-com.ELBIP.sslip.io left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

model directory structure

```
recommendation_model/
└── 1
    ├── assets
    ├── keras_metadata.pb
    ├── saved_model.pb
    └── variables
        ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
        └── variables.index
```

Not sure how to get serving to work as this is the last part of my pipeline

Answer (score 3):

When visiting the inferenceservice through the `LoadBalancer`, essentially the `istio-ingressgateway`, your request has an extra layer of control compared to the `NodePort`, which is dictated by the Istio security policy.

The response message of your curl indicates that you have an Istio installation with DEX authentication.

The [istio-dex guide](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/master/docs/samples/istio-dex) has examples of how to set the cookie for authenticating your inference request.